# Restrict Service Calendar to team

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am setting up CRM to enable the support team to be able to schedule service appointments. However the problem is that all users in the organisation are displayed as rows. How do I restrict this to just a single CRM Team rather than the whole organisation?

Using Dynamics Online 2016 Update 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create view that shows all users you want and next in calendar view change type to `user` and pick view that you created. You can't pick teams in there.

Comment: Slightly annoying that I have to do this as it means the view needs to be changed whenever the support team changes but it works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the Business Unit + Team + Security Role tandem to do this. How do you do this?

1. Create Child Business Units from the Parent Business Unit.
2. Create Teams with the same name
3. Create a Security Role (e.g Service Calendar BU Role) that restricts Service Calendar CRUD, Assign, Share, etc to Business Unit (Note: This entity can be found under Service Management)
4. Assign that Security Role (e.g Service Calendar BU Role) to the Team